# No log file in Texmaker after Miktex last update (2.9.6615 version)

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, miktex-update

(I have edited the post, with more information. It's my first post so sorry if I didn't explain the problem very well)

I have linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon (64 bits). After the Miktex's last update (2.9.6615 version), when compiling my .tex (let's call it A.tex) file in Texmaker I don't get the updated PDF file. I made a new .tex file (B.tex for example) and then texmaker showed a window saying that the program doesn't find the .log file, without any error. I have tried to uninstall both miktex and texmaker and then install them again (firstly miktex and then texmaker), the problem remained.

Also I have installed Texlive, since a read a suggestion of one of you, and then texwork as editor. I tried again to compile the B.tex and it worked well, however, with my old A.tex it drops and error:

LaTeX Error: File `Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls' not found

It seems that the program doesn't find the place where the class of the A.tex is defined, but I don't know why.
Before the last update of Miktex I hadn't had any problem and now I have it. That's why I guess it's because of the new version. I can't find the solution, hope there's somebody that could help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: If the new miktex version introduced a bug you should make a bug report at the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: Good point, I'll do it!

Comment: I'm lead to believe that MikTeX on Linux is in a bit of an experimental state still (not sure if that is exactly right), so you might as well try a vanilla TeX live: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864

Comment: For the link: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/75

Comment: Well you could have put a bit more effort in the bug report. E.g. which linux exactly, a minimal document that fails (and its name), if you can compile in the terminal, if the log-file is there, if you use options like --output-directory ...

Comment: I have edited the post with more information!

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the solution thanks to edocevoli from Miktex:

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/76

After the instructions given here, I compiled my A.tex file in Texmaker and it started a dialogue to install some more packages and that's it, it worked!

Thank you all